# Double Variable Summation

Tags: r, sum

So I've been attempting to do double summations on RStudio for awhile and I'm getting nowhere fast....  Does anyone know how to solve equations such as these:

[image]

So far, the code I did for the first summation is as followed:

```
IndexStart = 1

i = seq(IndexStart, 17, 1)

j = seq(IndexStart, 13, 1)

resultb = sum(i*j)

print(resultb)
```

For the second, since pi and pj have distinct values, I was going to list p1 and p2 as separate variables maybe with the above style of code?

Any input would be helpful

Comment: `sum(outer(i, j))`.

Comment: Or `sum((1:17)*sum(1:13))`

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas , this would also work similarly if I were adding i and j correct?

Comment: Yes but you would have to pass the function (`+`) as an argument. `outer` defaults to `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first summation can be computed with the help of `outer`.

```
i <- 1:17
j <- 1:13
sum(outer(i, j))
#[1] 13923
```

And do something similar for the second summation.
I will create test data, since you have posted none.

```
set.seed(1)    # Make the rsults reproducible
p.i <- runif(2)
p.j <- runif(2)

p.ij <- outer(p.i, p.j)
logp.ij <- log(p.ij)
sum(p.ij*logp.ij)
#[1] -1.325546
```